# Finding string and returning information from an adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Using Excel 2010. I need to see if a string in one set of cells exists in another set of cells, and if so, return information from the adjacent cell that matched that string.  I had originally done this with SEARCH, ISNUMBER and nested IF statements, but my source data set has several dozen entries in it, and the strings that must be searched has several hundred entries. The data resembles that in the picture (a simplified example):

[image]

For a limited data set, I used nested IF statements, like:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2,$A2,1)),"Cat Info",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$3,$A2,1)),"Dog Info",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$4,$A2,1)),"Elephant Info","Not Found")))
```

But now both sets of data are too large to do that on.

What I need to do is to search the strings in column A for the keyword in column D.  If the keyword is found, I need to return the corresponding information from column E.

For example, in column B2, since the word `dog` is in A2, I would want the contents of E3 (`Dog Section`) to be displayed in B2.

My list of keywords are unique (Column D, List) and I know that zero or one keyword will appear in the string in Column A (TheString).

I think that INDEX & MATCH functions may be part of my solution, but I am unsure how to find which List keyword is in the string and then return the Information column value.

Comment: How big is your keyword list?

Comment: If you have uniq list why dont use Find function?

Comment: @ergonaut - the list is several dozen, about 45, and subject to change.

Comment: Put your list in a dictionary, then iterate through the cells and the words in the cells (use SPLIT) and lookup the values in the dictionary. I can see two problems: 1) When there is more than one match in a single string (Cat hates dog) which one will it return 2) only exact matches will be found so it wouldn't pick up "Hamster" in your list

Comment: @Poof -I'm not sure how you mean.  The keyword list is several dozen (subject to change), and the string list is several hundred.  In column B2, I need to return the Information (Column E) for whichever keyword is found in A2.

Comment: Or go the other way and iterate through your list, finding every instance in the strings list and marking them. That solves problem 2 but not problem 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for VBA. This can be done with a simple formula:

Enter this formula in cell B2:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH(D$2:D$7,A2),E$2:E$7)
```

Copy downward as far as needed.

Note: adjust the range references to the size of your data.

Answer (score -2):

Not done it all, but this formula

=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,$A$1:$A$4,1)),ROW($A$1:$A$4),0))

Array Formula

Will give you the row of the A1:a4 where D1 etc, is contained.  Then you can index on that.  However it will only show the max row, so if its in 1 & 2, then it will only show row 2.

Cheers.